# Firebase Functions cannot compile TypeScript and ES Modules

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, es6-modules

I recently added Firebase Functions to my project with default settings (except changing value `"main": "src/index.ts",` in `package.json` because default path does not point correct file).

Here is my working code:

```
// index.ts

const { initializeApp } = require('firebase-admin/app');
const { onValueCreated } = require('firebase-functions/v2/database');
const { logger } = require('firebase-functions');

initializeApp();

exports.testFn = onValueCreated(
  '/users/{uid}/company/accounts/{accId}',
  (event) => {
    logger.log(event);
  }
);
```

And like I said, it works - I get proper log information in Firebase Emulator.
However, when I apply changes:

```
// index.ts

// Switched imports from require to ESM
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase-admin/app';
import { onValueCreated } from 'firebase-functions/v2/database';
import { logger } from 'firebase-functions';

initializeApp();

exports.testFn = onValueCreated(
  '/users/{uid}/company/accounts/{accId}',
  (event: any) => { // <-- added ': any' type to event, so it does not show .ts error
    logger.log(event);
  }
);
```

All I get is

```
shutdown requested via /__/quitquitquit

!!  functions: Failed to load function definition from source: FirebaseError: Functions codebase could not be analyzed successfully. It may have a syntax or runtime error
```

I checked and both those changes cause that error: I cannot either import ES Modules or use types.
I checked and I have `typescript` installed in `package.json`. Writing extension (like `.js` or `.ts`) at the end of ESM import is not working either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer for my question. It's not perfect, but it works.

#### I was using `firebase emulators:start` command which is not correct.

Generated by CLI Firebase Functions project has it's own commands inside `package.json`:

```
    "build": "tsc",
    "build:watch": "tsc --watch",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
```

We should use `npm run serve` instead.
Also keep `"main": "lib/index.js"` in `package.json` as it is. Now this solution will compile TypeScript code to JavaScript and put it in `lib/index.js` and our application can use both ES Modules and TypeScript.

#### Recompiling problem

I have no idea how to force recompilation on save, even having  `"compileOnSave": true` set in `tsconfig.json`. My workaround is to have second terminal opened and use `npm run build` each time I need to recompile it.

If anyone (or me) will find solution for that, I'll edit that post.

#### More services in Firebase Emulator

I also removed `--only functions` from `serve` command in `package.json` so all my needed Firebase serviced are being emulated locally.